# Send hex command to ESC/POS Printer Android

Tags: java, android, printing, hex, thermal-printer

I am working on an application that needs to print directly to an ESC/POS printer.  Printing is fine, however when issuing commands to the printer they just print!!
I'm trying to convert some c# code and the commands I'm trying to send are hex strings as follows:

```
public static String PRINTLOGOCOMPANY = "\x1c\x70\x01\x30";
```

Of course I understand that there are illegal escape characters in this so I changed it to:

```
"\\x1c\\x70\\x01\\x30"
```

I then converted to a byte array and tried sending it via a dataoutput stream like so:

```
String WIDTH_1 ="\\x1d\\x57\\x120\\x01";

Log.i("Width String: ", WIDTH_1);
final byte [] width = WIDTH_1.getBytes();
final int portNo =  xxxx;
final String ipAddress = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx";

Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress, portNo);
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            dOut.writeInt(width.length);
            dOut.write(width);
            dOut.close();
            sock.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Unknown Host Exception Error: ", String.valueOf(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("IO Exception Error: ", String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
};
thread.start(
```

but it just prints it on the other end;

Could anyone offer any advice on this Id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: does nobody have any info on this topic? pulling my hair out here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can't send commands to printer, it just prints all of your symbols. All you need is send bytes. For example, to open the till you need to do:

```
Socket mSocket = new Socket(PRINTER_IP, PRINTER_PORT);
OutputStream mPrinter = mSocket.getOutputStream();
mPrinter.write(0x1B);
mPrinter.write(0x70);
mPrinter.write(0);              
mPrinter.write(200);  // t1 
mPrinter.write(255);  // t2
```

Comment: Thank you very much...however, I have problem where by the requirement is the logos for a company are already stored on the printer.  So I need to print the logo, then some text, then another logo, in the c# code it seems one big string is created appending the bytes for example:  `StringBuilder sb; String logo1 = "x12/x52/x1b/x2c"; String text = "this is a test string"; String logo2 = "x12/x52/x1b/x2c"; sb.append(logo1);sb.append(text); sb.append(logo2);`  They are then sending the string to printer..is this possible in Java/Android?   Or when trying for format text (embolden etc)

Comment: You need to send byte array(or byte by byte like my example), not string. Try send "x12/x52/x1b/x2c" as 0x12, 0x52, 0x1B, 0x2C etc. For more information(list of commands) try look manuals, for example http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf